# Converting SMS and MMS

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm programming an Android application which needs to send a SMS/MMS message to any mobile ( I mean from this application to any mobile). Also any mobile should be able to send an SMS to this application...

Can anyone please inform me how can I do it (convert a SMS\MMS)... is there any code for that?

Comment: MMS is an xml file. You just have to take the sms text and add it in a node. It is as simple as that.

Comment: thx, but i need a code which mks it more understandable and i wanna know how the mobile application recognize that SMS is for it ????